# Why do I get a list of null values when I print out values from TreeMap?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and am using the TreeMap Code example that was on this site but when I try to iterate through the TreeMap, I get a list of null values but when I print the map directly I can see the key/value pairs. How do I rectify this?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String,Double> map = new HashMap<String,Double>();
        ValueComparator1 bvc =  new ValueComparator1(map);
        TreeMap<String,Double> sorted_map = new TreeMap<String,Double>(bvc);

        map.put("A",99.5);
        map.put("B",67.4);
        map.put("C",67.4);
        map.put("D",67.3);

        System.out.println("unsorted map: "+map);

        sorted_map.putAll(map);


        System.out.println("results: "+sorted_map);

        for(String key: sorted_map.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println(sorted_map.get(key)); //null values-Why?
        }
    }
}

class ValueComparator1 implements Comparator<String> {

    Map<String, Double> base;
    public ValueComparator1(Map<String, Double> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    // Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals.    
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } // returning 0 would merge keys
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work because your comparator doesn't return 0 when given identical keys, e.g. compare("A", "A").  Change it to

```
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        Double va = base.get(a);
        Double vb = base.get(b);
        if(va > vb) {
            return -1;
        } else if(va < vb) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return a.compareTo(b);
        }
    }
```

and it'll work.

Comment: Is that just something that is required? Because all my keys are different in the example. Still don't understand the reasoning behind this edit. It works btw.

Comment: It's necessary because when you call get("A"), and the map looks at the entry for "A", your original comparator says the keys are not equal, so it won't return that entry.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but your example is a bit upside down. You're putting keys into a sorted map (tree map) but then using the values as keys in the sense that you compare by the values. It looks like you're looking to handle objects that have a key and a value, so here's something you might want to consider. This would certainly be the OOP way to handle "compound" concepts like the one you're modeling with a map.

```
class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
    String value;
    double key;

    Pair(String value, double key) {
        this.value = value;
        this.key = key;
    }

    public int compareTo(Pair p) {
        return Double.compare(key, p.key);
    }

    public String toString(Pair p) {
        return value + "," + key;
    }
}

static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Pair> unsortedSet = new HashSet<Pair>();
    unsortedSet.add(new Pair("A", 99.5));
    unsortedSet.add(new Pair("B", 67.4));
    unsortedSet.add(new Pair("C", 67.4));
    unsortedSet.add(new Pair("D", 67.3));

    Set<Pair> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Pair>();
    sortedSet.add(new Pair("A", 99.5));
    sortedSet.add(new Pair("B", 67.4));
    sortedSet.add(new Pair("C", 67.4));
    sortedSet.add(new Pair("D", 67.3));

    System.out.println("Unsorted set: " + unsortedSet);
    System.out.println("Sorted set: " + sortedSet);

    for (Pair pair : sortedSet) {
        System.out.println(pair);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your comparator never returns 0 TreeMap.get() does not work. Still you can iterate over TreeMap entries like this

```
    for (Entry<String, Double> e : sorted_map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

prints

```
A=99.5
C=67.4
B=67.4
D=67.3
```

Comment: Consistency with equals is certainly ideal, but not always required for TreeMap.  According to the docs, "The behavior of a sorted map is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Map interface."

Answer (score 0):

The code of Adam Crume is very important.  To explain you more on this, when you call your `sorted_map.get(key)`, it goes to `java.util.TreeMap` class', `getEntryUsingComparator` method because you have set the comparator explicitly. This method looks like

```
final Entry<K,V> getEntryUsingComparator(Object key) {
        K k = (K) key;
        Comparator<? super K> cpr = comparator;
        if (cpr != null) {
            Entry<K,V> p = root;
            while (p != null) {
                int cmp = cpr.compare(k, p.key);
                if (cmp < 0)
                    p = p.left;
                else if (cmp > 0)
                    p = p.right;
                else
                    return p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Since there is comparison for keys in your `compare` method  of your value comparator, the  entry will be null and hence value will also be null because `map.get` is implemented as

```
 public V get(Object key) {
        Entry<K,V> p = getEntry(key);
        return (p==null ? null : p.value);
    }
```